# Vertical line view not showing when running the app on my phone

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I want to make a vertical line at the start of each item in a list view, it looks great at the android studio preview screen as shown in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23kU1.png)

But when i run it on my phone it doesn't appear, any idea why? [screenshoot from my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3SaZ.png)

Here is the XML script for item_view.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:maxHeight="80dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">
<View
    android:id="@+id/line2"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_item_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Tesla Stock's Terrible Week: A Buying Opportunity?"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/line2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_item_by"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:text="By"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_item_title"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_item_name"
    tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="19dp"
    tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="336dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_item_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:text="Fool.com"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_item_by"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_item_title" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Read More"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_item_name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/iv_arrow"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_item_name" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_arrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I didn't change any attributes from java code.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because you're using ConstraintLayout which has it's own rules.

Instead of using:

```
<View
android:id="@+id/line2"
android:layout_width="1dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
```

Use:

```
<View
android:id="@+id/line2"
android:layout_width="1dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
```

Essentially, if you look at this documentation on [ConstraintLayout's Dimensions Constraints](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#DimensionConstraints), you'll see that it mentions about not using MATCH_PARENT and to use MATCH_CONSTRAINT (aka 0dp) instead.

Also, you need to add in the top and bottom constraints so that the ConstraintLayout knows how to size it's height.